# What method needs implemented to get an action from the UITableViewCell click / touch?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to the UITableView and noticed that w/out implementing a method the UITableViewCell simply turns blue when it's touched.  What method would I need to add to get some action from this touch directly?

For example, when the cell is clicked I want to pass off the index to another method that will in turn do the same action that is completed by the accessory button click event.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [didSelectRowAtIndexPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a) method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // indexPath.row tells you index of row tapped
    // here do whatever your logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

[Link here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to the table view, and implement one or more of the following 2 methods in the delegate class, depending on when you want the event to be fired:

```
-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```